# how open set timezone setting in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, settings, android-tv

I am trying to open `set timezone setting` on Android TV programmatically. I have found `Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS)` that opens date and time settings but what I want is open `set timezone setting` which is one step ahead.
I need to open set timezone settings directly.
ow can I do that?

Comment: "what I want is open set timezone setting which is one step ahead" -- where time zone settings are in relation to `ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS` is up to the device manufacturer. "I need to open set timezone settings directly" -- contact the device manufacturer and see if they have some undocumented means of launching directly to that screen.